# Setting order property of group of divs. (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.container:nth-child(2) div').children('div').each(function (index) {
                this.css('order',index)
            });
        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <p>20</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>35</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>-15</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>7</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>55</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>-22</p>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

What I would like is to set the flexbox order attribute of each div inside the **second** container div to the current index of the each function.

However my script does not work as intended. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: At least you have a duplicate `<div class="container">` inside your HTML.

Comment: @Roy Hence the _"...inside the **second** container div..."_

Comment: Remove `.children('div')`. The first selector already gets the `<div>`s in the container.

Comment: @Andreas I tried doing it. Now I get a Uncaught TypeError saying that "this.css" is not a function.

Comment: `this` in an event handler is a DOM node and not a jQuery object. And you're missing a closing `</div>` for the first `.container` (see my answer)

Comment: @Andreas Oh, sorry it is closed, I just removed some of the html unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- <s>The first `.container` is missing the closing `</div>`</s>
- The selector `$('.container:nth-child(2) div')` already gets the child `<div>`s hence the following `.children('div')` won't find anything
- `this` inside the event handler is the DOM node (the `<div>`) and not a jQuery object, hence there's no `.css()` available

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container:nth-child(2) div').each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('order', index)
           .text(index); // just for visualization
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <p>20</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>35</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>-15</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>55</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>-22</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed some of the html unrelated to my question and accidentally deleted the closing tag :) But thanks this works.